# Is there a way to output the events that belong in a month after a specific date using the Calendar plugin by Solspace?

Tags: solspace, plugin-solspacecalendar

I would like to get the events with all their occurrences that belong to a specific month but ignore any of those occurrences before a certain date.
From the documentation, the `dateRangeStart` parameter should the trick but it doesn't work for me. The following query returns all events starting from December 1st.

```
{% set month = craft.calendar.month({
    dateRangeStart: '2017-12-17',
    calendar: calendarHandle
}) %}
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The `calendar.month` function is designed to only display complete months, so as long as you specify a date, it's going to show you events for that whole month (before and after).

What you're looking for is the `calendar.events` function:
https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/calendar.events/

The code to display events starting from **today** plus 1 month (+30 days) would look something like this:

```
{% set events = craft.calendar.events({
   dateRangeStart: 'today',
   dateRangeEnd: '30 days'
}) %}
```

If you're looking to display events starting **today** but stop and the **END of the current month**, your code would look something like this:

```
{% set events = craft.calendar.events({
   dateRangeStart: 'today',
   dateRangeEnd: 'last day of +0 month'
}) %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm a bit confused by this. What is the purpose of the `dateRangeStart` and `dateRangeEnd` as mentioned in the [documentation for craft.calendar.month](https://solspace.com/craft/calendar/docs/calendar.month/#parameters)? The reason I'm asking is that I want to output the events of a specific month grouped by days as in `{% for week in month %} {% for day in week %} ... ` which from what I understand is not possible using `craft.calendar.events.`

Comment: Honestly, I think those are errors in the documentation. I will double check with our lead developer and then remove them. Sorry for the confusion.